# Finder Share Extension: Getting a preview image from NSItemProvider

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, finder, macos-high-sierra

I'm creating a Finder Share extension to be used when selecting a file.  I'd like to show an image preview of the file that you are sharing (like you see in the Messages and Twitter Finder Share extensions, for example).

In the loadView method of the view controller for my share extension, I'm doing this:

```
let item = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
if let attachments = item.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {
    if let attachment = attachments.first {

        attachment.loadPreviewImage(options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in
            if error != nil {
                //handle error...
            } else if let img = item as? NSImage {
                //put image preview in my "share sheet"...
            }
        })

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I keep hitting the error condition.  The error that I'm getting is:

Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load preview." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load preview.}

For what it's worth, I **am** able to call attachment.loadItem() successfully and work with the file.  But I don't really care to do anything with the file itself at this point, I just want a thumbnail image that represents the file which theoretically this method should give me...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. After read the manual, I think here is the reason.

"Loads the preview image for the item that is represented by the item provider."

However, it is not forced that the item provider must provides a preview. So the error simply says that there is no preview that the item provider can provide. You should do it yourself.